# Is $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ monotonically increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Is $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ monotonically increasing where $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\cdot\|$ is an arbitrary norm? I could show that it is true for $p$-norms, but I have not been able to come up with a proof for an arbitrary norm or a counter-example.

Edit: By monotonically increasing, I mean in each component: $\frac{x_i}{\|x\|}$ is increasing in $x_i$ for any $i \in [n]$ (and any fixed values for the other components).

Edit2:
To make it clearer, consider two vectors $x$ and $x'$ where $x_j' > x_j$ and $x'_i = x_i$ for all $i \neq j$. Is it true that $\frac{x'_j}{\|x'\|} \geq \frac{x_j}{\|x\|}$?

Comment: Consider the $1$-norm with respect to a rotation $\theta \in (0, \pi/4)$ of the standard basis.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general norms, this is false.  We can actually find a counterexample by considering the $1$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but we have to consider the $1$-norm  not respect to the standard basis but with respect to, for instance, the basis $(\sqrt{3}/2, 1/2), (-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$.

Then when $x = (\sqrt{3}/2, 1/2)$ we have $x/\|x\| = x$, but $$\frac{x+t(1,0)}{\|x + t(1,0)\|} \xrightarrow{t\to\infty} (\sqrt{3}-1,0)$$
and $\sqrt{3}-1 < \sqrt{3}/2$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for $p$-norms. Let $x\equiv(0,1)$ and $y\equiv(3,4)$.
Then, $\Vert x\Vert_{2}=1$ and $\Vert y\Vert_{2}=5$. However,
$$
\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert_{2}}=\frac{(0,1)}{1}
\text{ and }
\frac{y}{\Vert y\Vert_{2}}=\frac{(3,4)}{5}.
$$

Comment: Your interpretation seems stronger than the one given in the question (which is quite weak)

Comment: Yes, this isn't a counter-example to what I meant. I added a second edit to my question to make it clearer.